# Streaming service choices and setup

Tags: node.js, live-streaming

I'm trying to create a service that livestreams my webcam on the web. Should i use Red5 or trying to set it up on my own with WebRTC and getUserMedia? If yes, how? Any kind of tip is accepted! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use WOWZA  but its not free soruce.
You can use webRTC for live tream and you will also need SSL configured for webRTC.

Answer (score 0):

1.- install red5 server
2.- run red5 server.
3.- open port, 1935, 5080, 80, 8080, on router and firewall. desactive firewall 
    antivirus.
4.- install and run flash media live encoder.
5.- in FMLE: put your webcam configuration, this have autodetect.
6.- FMS: rtmp://YOUR LOCAL IP/oflaDemo, stream: live. connect and next start.
7.- use flash player for video ej: fwplayer or other.
8.- create file html, paste code for player and configure directions.
9.- in this case, use isp ip ej: rtmp:/ISP IP:1935/oflaDemo
    file: Live. Nota: use rtmp port 1935. save.
    put your page in the wb, or create folder in red5/webapps/root/and save file 
    html in your new folder.
10. in case of save in red5folders, you can see your webcam on live here 
    http://ISP IP:5080/YOUR FOLDER/FLASPLAYER.html.
11.- this direccion is http: see other port 5080 for this.

NOTE: en local mode just use local ip, change thi on FMLE and Flashplayer file html.